# VIM remote file saving too slow

Tags: vim

I am working with remote files with VIM. When I save any file (:w), changes does not effect straight away. For example, if i change html or css file and when i try to see the changes on browser, it does not show me the changes after my first save command (:w). I go to VIM again and save it again by :w. Then I can see the changes and sometimes need to apply 3/4 times :w to see the changes.

Can anybody please tell me the actual process to save the remote file so that I can see my changes just after saving the file. Thanks.

Comment: Are you **sure** this is a problem with [tag:vim]? Perhaps your browser is showing you a cached copy...

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an issue with your browser's cache. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should reload the page in Chrome without cache.

Answer (score 2):

Vim usually saves changes to disk on a `:w` (write action on either local or remote host).

If you're editing remote files, then perhaps use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to save and exit the file - that way you will know that the changes have been saved before vim exits.

If it's an HTML file you're editing, try and add the following tags to your code (in the `<head>`):

```
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

This should prevent any automatic (or configured) caching by browsers. Cache control is also possible by using most scripting languages.

Comment: ~ I checked whether it is using cached copy clearing cache before opening it in the browser but its the same.

Comment: hi Nickhar, I tried adding the above meta tag. But its the same. thanks.